# Can I create a new membership for an existing contact using CiviCRM Drupal Webforms?

Tags: drupal, webforms, membership, civicrm

I am using CiviCRM's webform module for Drupal and I'd like to be able of setting it up a form that does the following:

1. locate the **existing contact** rather than creating a new one,
2. **add a new membership** record for the contact (no matter if the contact has already one or more memberships).

If I set the form by checking **existing contact** (or by setting a deduplication rule), as soon as the form is submitted, CiviCRM will try to find an existing contact and will do the same thing for the membership.

This means that for contacts with existing memberships, their membership records are updated rather than new membership records being created for those contacts.

- Am I maybe missing an **existing membership** checkbox somewhere?
- Is there a way, without coding, so I can create a new membership for an existing contact using CiviCRM Drupal Webforms?

**1st Edit**: Following the suggestion from the 1st comment, this question has been reposted. Please follow the discussion in https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/41940/can-i-create-a-new-membership-for-an-existing-contact-using-civicrm-drupal-webfo

Comment: Post your question on https://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You're right. This isn't the right forum. Thanks for the clarification! I just reposted the question in https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/41940/can-i-create-a-new-membership-for-an-existing-contact-using-civicrm-drupal-webfo